# R Highcharter - How to customize tooltips for multiple y-axes?

Tags: r, r-highcharter

Is it possible to customize tooltip pointformat for multiple y-axes? In the simple example below, I have two y-axes: one for value and one for percentage. I want the tooltip to show `${point.y:,.0f}` for the value series, and `{point.y:,.2f}%` for the percentage series.

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_yAxis_multiples(list(title=list(text="<b>Value<b>"),
                          showLastLabel = FALSE,opposite = FALSE),
                     list(title=list(text="<b>Percent<b>"),
                          showLastLabel = FALSE,  opposite = T)) %>%
  hc_add_series(c(seq(100,110)), yAxis=0) %>%
  hc_add_series(c(seq(1,10)), yAxis=1)
```

I tried to add `hc_tooltip(list(pointFormat = "<b>{series.name}: ${point.y:,.0f}",pointFormat = "<b>{series.name}: {point.y:,.2f}%"))`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Ben, when you set `shared = TRUE`, all the tooltips will show up in one window. That's what `shared` means. What I'm trying to do is to customize the individual tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the tooltip for each individual `hc_add_series`:

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_yAxis_multiples(list(title=list(text="<b>Value<b>"),
                          showLastLabel = FALSE,opposite = FALSE),
                     list(title=list(text="<b>Percent<b>"),
                          showLastLabel = FALSE,  opposite = T)) %>%
  hc_add_series(c(seq(100,110)), yAxis=0,
                tooltip = list(pointFormat = "<b>{series.name}: ${point.y:,.0f}")) %>%
  hc_add_series(c(seq(1,10)), yAxis=1,
                tooltip = list(pointFormat = "<b>{series.name}: {point.y:,.2f}%"))
```